# Trigger to keep calculated data updated in DB2

Tags: sql, database, database-design, triggers, db2

I have to maintain an integer updated consistently, so I want to make a trigger (or something related) that calculates the data and keeps it updated every time.

This is:

I have a table with the attributes: Working, Balance and Must_Work. I want to keep Working and Balance updated.

Working is the SUM of values stored in other tables.

Balance is the difference between Working and Must_work.

So far I've got this

```
CREATE TRIGGER calculateWorkload
AFTER INSERT ON SEMESTER_WORKLOAD
FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2SQL
BEGIN
    UPDATE SEMESTER_WORKLOAD SET WORKING =
    (SELECT SUM(WORKING_HOURS) FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT ID_MODULE, WORKING_HOURS FROM LECTURE WHERE ID_SW = ????))
    WHERE ID_SW = ????

INSERT INTO t1.ACCOUNT (SELECT  t1.ACADEMIC_SEMESTER, t1.ID_LECTURER, t1.WORKLOAD, t3.WORKING_HOURS FROM SEMESTER_WORKLOAD t1
INNER JOIN LECTURER t2 ON t1.ID_LECTURER = t2.ID_LECTURER
INNER JOIN LECTURE t3 ON t1.ID_SW = t3.ID_SW WHERE

END
```

Problem is, how can I make it do it for every value and not only for a given value? And after that, how do I make it so it keeps the data updated?

Comment: Have you looked into materialized query tables?

Comment: Or just simply views?